# How to parse the SNS notification message in aws lambda using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline

I have created SNS notification topic to receive  notification for code pipeline succeed or failure, every time new code is deployed in aws codepipeline. The message that I am receiving by subscribing to aws sns topic is in json format and not easily readable. How can I make it more readable?

I have seen few articles saying ,to use lambda for that. Someone who can guide how can I parse these message using python

Comment: You can also use eventbrige rule's input transformer. How do you get the event which you then send via sns?

Comment: Are you just trying to parse JSON with Python?  What have you tried?  What tutorials have you tried?  There are hundreds of useful pages when I do a search.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to subscribe to a SNS topic and receive the notification in a prettified format.
In simpler terms, you want to transform the event you receive via SNS. AWS Lambda can come handy in these situations.
Assuming you know how to use SNS topic as trigger with lambda, this is how the handler of your lambda might look,

```
def handler(event, context):
  for record in event['Records']:
    parse_notification_here
```

For details on how to use SNS as trigger for AWS Lambda - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for you cause I am not entirely sure of your scenario.

You could publish the SNS topic's message based on whether the code pipeline succeeded or failed, to make it more easy to read.

```
sns = boto3.client('sns')
response = sns.publish(
    TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:region:account-id:topic-name',
    Message='failure' # or succeeded 
)
```

How can I make it more readable? As you know, the message that you receive from the subscribed SNS topic is basically in JSON format, according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html), it normally looks like this:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:sns-lambda:21be56ed-a058-49f5-8c98-aedd2564c486",
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "Sns": {
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Timestamp": "2019-01-02T12:45:07.000Z",
        "Signature": "tcc6faL2yUC6dgZdmrwh1Y4cGa/ebXEkAi6RibDsvpi+tE/1+82j...65r==",
        "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-ac565b8b1a6c5d002d285f9598aa1d9b.pem",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "Message": "Hello from SNS!",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        },
        "Type": "Notification",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&amp;SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:test-lambda:21be56ed-a058-49f5-8c98-aedd2564c486",
        "TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:sns-lambda",
        "Subject": "TestInvoke"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So, how can I parse these messages using the AWS Lambda function(python)? Here is the sample code for you.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # extract the SNS message from the Lambda event

    # get event version
    event_version = event['Records'][0]['EventVersion']
    print(f"event_version: {event_version}")

    # get sns message
    sns_message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    print(f"sns_message: {sns_message}")

    # get sns timestamp
    sns_timestamp = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Timestamp']
    print(f"sns_timestamp: {sns_stamp}")
```